# jQM/PhoneGap: Navigation started when state=1 bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've overcome a frustrating problem with jQuery Mobile only to run into another one. Here's the story:
I'm using $.mobile.changePage() as shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#submitroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dieRoll = $("#dieresult").val();

    $.mobile.changePage('valueresult.html', {
        data: {
                arg1: dieRoll
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click on the button (#submitroll), it doesn't transition to the valueresult.html page (which resides in the same directory as the origin page). Instead, the console output produces the following error:

> Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1

I searched on that error and found many results, most of them referring to a bug in PhoneGap 2.7. I happened to be running PhoneGap 2.8.1, so I figured/hoped that was the issue. I noticed  PhoneGap 2.9rc1 available (which, according to the release notes, includes a fix to that particular bug), so I installed 2.9rc1 just to see if it would fix the problem.... and it didn't.

But before I inform the PhoneGap folks, I want to rule out the (strong) possibility that I'm doing something wrong.

I'm running jQuery 1.10.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, currently building/testing on iOS 6.1. If anyone has any suggestions on how to proceed, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using a `<button>` tag? or something else?

Comment: I'm using this:
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="submitroll">Submit</a>
I ended up resolving this issue. I'll explain in my response to the below comment.

Answer (score 3):

For everyones interest! Maybe the only reasy why this error appears is, becaus the new loaded page maybe produces some javascript errors!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in PhoneGap at the moment. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3530

Comment: Right, I realize that. And the release notes for 2.9rc1 specifically state that bug 3530 is fixed. Hence my post.
It turns out that I was able to work-around the problem. But doing rel="external" on my hyperlink. It's not what I wanted to do, but it works.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. You should submit your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a workaround. If you can, try to have 2 more pages which the first will have a link to the second page using data-ajax="false" like

```
<a href="your-second-page/index.html" data-ajax="false">Middle step ></a>
```

... then you will have on the second page the normal link

```
<a href="your-current-page-with-your-form/index.html" data-ajax="true">Your current form page ></a>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case I had exactly the same issue when use `Beta Xcode` (Version 6.3 (6D543q))

For 'Stable' Xcode app works right way.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was only caused by using jQuery.mobile.changePage('new page.html') when the real page was Newpage.html

So, check your capitalization, especially if you're developing on a PC but deploying to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means it's a bad URL. Check the link.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old issue, but without a marked solution.

For me the following error:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
```

causing cordova/phonegap app to "flash screen, not do the action" on iOS, got resolved by changing

```
<a href="#" ...>
```

to

```
<a ...>
```

i.e. by removing the `href="#"` part from the `<a>`-tag.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a security issue in that I run inline javascript in my app. Comment out the following from index.html:

```
   <!-- 
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
 -->
```

Answer (score -3):

I have an salesforce app,developed using custom code,in my scenario  I am accessing  the app using salesforce1 mobile using ipad,in a visuval force component I have an link which populate an Java script dialog using below code.It was working fine in the browser,here we restricted the display text length is 8 char,it is working fine in browsers upto last week working fine in the Ipad,last week onwards I am seeing below message in the event logs

2017/04/20 18:41:47.331 Chatter[1312:1b257] ERROR com.salesforce.salesforce1.auraintegration : WKWebView did fail navigation.
Current URL:
Error: Error Domain=SFWKWebViewDelegate Code=1 "Navigation started when state=1" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Navigation started when state=1}.
2017/04/20 18:41:47.331 Chatter[1312:18d77] ERROR com.salesforce.salesforce1.auraintegration : [aura integration] -, root app initialized:1, failed to load touch component:1, Navigation started when state=1
2017/04/20 18:41:47.331 Chatter[1312:1b257] ERROR com.salesforce.salesforce1.auraintegration : [aura integration] - Run into error:Navigation started when state=1
2017/04/20 18:41:57.555 Chatter[1312:84c3] INFO com.salesforce : Submit action GET /services/data/v32.0/connect/notifications

below one is my visual force page code

```
<a href="#"
   class="classname" 
   id="add_link_{!mergefield}" 
   onclick="JavaScript function"
   html-data-profile="{!mergefield}"
   html-data-market="{!mergefield}"
   html-data-lob="{!mergefield}"                                                        
   html-data-product="{!mergefield}"
   html-data-brand="{!mergefield}"
>
  <apex:outputText rendered="{!mergefield}">
    Change
  </apex:outputText>
</a>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.  (and please tab your code properly)